# Want to locate old databases

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

After installing a new window on my laptop, my databases got lost because I installed new xampp again in c drive. Before changing window, xampp was installed in f drive instead of c drive. So, right now, I have two xampp folders. 1 is in C drive (newly installed) and other is in F drive (old xampp). And that old folder is still having all projects and files as it is. But now the problem is that when I open "localhost/...", It opens mySql where no database exists. Is there any way to get my .sql databases back to original so that I can save a lot of time of mine. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to locate your old db...
you can only access your db with tables but can't recover you data in the tables...
Follow this...
Drive location:\xampp\mysql\data

Here you can find you db..
Just copy db that you want and place that into your newly install xampp(mysql\data).

Comment: You saved me a lot of time and effort. It was really hectic for me to create the whole database again. 
Thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/users/9848630/ammar-mehr

Comment: Welcome dude...Stay Connected